# Three.js : intersectObjects object not responding to color change [jsfiddle]

Tags: javascript, three.js

For some reason I am not able to change the color of a cube when a person mouses over it.  I distilled the code down to the most barebones I could.

http://jsfiddle.net/pgd3d5rf/

```
<script>
var container;
var scene, camera, renderer, mouse, raycaster;
var grid_items = [];

init();
grid();
render();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 500, 800, 1300 );
    camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3() );

    // Lights
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x606060 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x808080 );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
}

function grid(){
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    grid_items.push(cube);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;

    console.log(mouse.x+"-"+mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(grid_items);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            console.log("OBJECT "+intersects[i])
            intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
        }
    }
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Or use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612407/three-js-raycaster-not-selecting-right-object/27621578#27621578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-render after changing the color. So add a call to `render();` just after you changed the colors:

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        console.log("OBJECT "+intersects[i]);
        intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
    }
    render();
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgd3d5rf/1/

Comment: Thanks so much.  So simple / obvious but I am new to three.js

Comment: You have come far :) Only rendering when needed saves a lot of performance. But usually you would use ```requestAnimationFrame( render );``` inside your ```render()``` function to re-render your scene at a target of 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

With the `CanvasRenderer()` your fiddle is not working but if I change it to `WebGLRenderer()` then if you add a `render()` call at the end of your `onDocumentMouseMove()` function it should work.