# How to use Three.js mouse picking

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse-picking

I would like to add object picking to this code:

```
var Three = new function () {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene()

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
    this.camera.position.set(20, 52, 20);
    this.camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
    this.camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4;
    this.camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2));
    this.camera.scale.addScalar(1);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(436, 624), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/maps/1.png')}));
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2; //-90 degrees around the x axis
    this.scene.add(ground);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFDD);
    light.position.set(-1000, 1000, 1000);
    this.scene.add(light);

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    this.loadCastle = function (color, x, y) {
        loader.load('/models/castle.json', getGeomHandler(color, x * 4 - 214, y * 4 - 309, 0.5));
    }
    this.init = function () {
        $('#game').append(Three.renderer.domElement);
        Three.render();
    }
    this.render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(Three.render);
        Three.renderer.render(Three.scene, Three.camera);
    };
}
```

How can I do this in the simplest way?

p.s.
There are only castles meshes loaded with "loadCastle" method and I want to be able to pick them.

Edit:

I tried AlmazVildanov sugestion like this:

```
function getGeomHandler(color, x, y, scale) {
    return function (geometry) {
        var model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color}));
        model.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        model.position.set(x, 0, y);
        model.name = color + '_' + x + '_' + y;
        Three.scene.add(model);
        EventsControls.attach(model);
    };
}

EventsControls = new EventsControls(Three.camera, Three.renderer.domElement);
EventsControls.displacing = false;
EventsControls.onclick = function () {
    console.log('aaa')
    console.log(this.focused.name)
}
```

but when I'm clicking on models nothing happens, no messages in console.

EDIT 2:
Object picking is working fine. Solved.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250810/three-js-get-object-name-with-mouse-click/26311582#26311582)

Comment: @AlmazVildanov where can I get EventsControls.js?

Comment: [here](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/controls/EventsControls.js)

Comment: @AlmazVildanov what if I have a lot of meshes but only few will be subject of picking, can I programmatically ignore them with your lib?

Comment: Yes. With code `EventsControls.attach( model );` or
`EventsControls.detach( model );`

Comment: @AlmazVildanov I edited my code. Can you look at it and tell me if I do something wrong?

Comment: The model must be loaded after the declaration of `EventsControls`. This is done?

Comment: This was strange: I switched to Firefox becase Chrom couldn't handle this much of meshes I was loading so I was testing it in Firefox. But Firebug didn't show me error messages that Firefox couldn't read EventsControls.js file (or maybe I didn't know where to search for it). Now I limited numer of meshes and switched back to Chrome and there was this error in console about file access problems. So sorry for stupid question, it was problem with file permissions and everything is working fine now.

Comment: ok, good. I'm glad that it works)

Comment: Ok, I have EventControls implemented and it is working but I don't know how to handle situation when I click on the ground (it is one big plane mesh). How can I get coordinates of that point on the ground (I have only coordinates of that big mesh)?

Comment: `EventsControls.attach( youGround );` ?

Comment: I have it attached but will this.intersects[0].point in onclick work? Is it right way to do it?

Comment: Yes =) `this.intersects[0].point`

Comment: How can I distinguish between left and right mouse button?

Comment: right mouse button = shift+click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my question is to use @AlmazVildanov EventsControls