# Three.js How to DragControl Object3D?

Tags: three.js

When I load jSON Object to the scene using ObjectLoader, I can't assign DragControls to them. But a mesh is added to the Loader, I can assign  dragcontrollers.

I used this source code for my projects 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( model_url , function ( object ) {
    splineHelperObjects.push( object );
    splinePointsLength++;
    scene.add( object );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Object3D have to to included into a mesh. Then it can be added to helper objects.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( model_url , function ( object ) {

   var cylBleu = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0 });
   var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh( object.children[0].geometry, cylBleu );`

   newMesh.add(object);
   splineHelperObjects.push( object );
   splinePointsLength++;
   scene.add( object );
});
```

Comment: or use [evencontrols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250810/three-js-get-object-name-with-mouse-click/26311582#26311582)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to use Collision detection to limit movements after collusion happens?

Comment: Is `newMesh.add(object)` the same as `object.children[0].add(object)`? And you're just `splineHelperObjects.push(object)`? How would the `object` become draggable by `DragControls` with that?